# YAML multi-line regex trim comments and whitespace

Tags: node.js, json, yaml, vscode-extensions

How do I write a regular expression in yaml across multiple lines that, when converted to json, is a single line without extra spaces or comments?

The [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#using-yaml-to-write-a-grammar) outline a way to write a single regular expression in yaml that spans multiple lines with comments. I've tried their suggestions, and my output always includes the newlines and comments.

Here's the yaml from their example, saved at `syntaxes/abc.tmLanguage.yaml`:

```yaml
---
match: >
  (?x)
    \s*             # Leading whitespace
    (\[)([^]]+?)(\])(:)    # reference name
    [ \t]*       # optional whitespace
    (<?)(\S+?)(>?)     # The url
    (?:
        ((\().+?(\)))     # Match title in quotes
      | ((").+?("))    # or in parens
    )?       # Title is optional
    \s*     # Optional whitespace
    $
name: meta.link.reference.def.markdown
```

I then install the [js-yaml](https://npmjs.org/package/js-yaml) tool like suggested, and run the following command:

```sh
$ npx js-yaml syntaxes/abc.tmLanguage.yaml > syntaxes/abc.tmLanguage.json
```

The generated `syntaxes/abc.tmLanguage.json` file contains all the the whitespace and comments

```
{
  "match": "(?x)\n  \\s*             # Leading whitespace\n  (\\[)([^]]+?)(\\])(:)    # reference name\n  [ \\t]*       # optional whitespace\n  (<?)(\\S+?)(>?)     # The url\n  (?:\n      ((\\().+?(\\)))     # Match title in quotes\n    | ((\").+?(\"))    # or in parens\n  )?       # Title is optional\n  \\s*     # Optional whitespace\n  $\n",
  "name": "meta.link.reference.def.markdown"
}
```

I then tried pasting my above yaml into [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv), [json2yaml.com](https://www.json2yaml.com/convert-yaml-to-json), [convertjson.com](https://www.convertjson.com/yaml-to-json.htm) and more, all with similar results.

I've also tried a few variations of yaml multi-line operators like `>-`, `|`, `|-`, etc, but none solved the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of that is a problem if you process the regex in [free-spacing mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html). The comments and whitespace will be thrown away by the regex engine. Folded scalars in YAML will produce at least one space token per line break, so you can't really use it to write regexes without free-spacing mode anyway.

Here's a breakdown *why* YAML parses your input like this:

The first issue is a peculiar definition [in the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796671) about the handling of folded scalars:

> Lines starting with white space characters (more-indented lines) are not folded.

Your first line defines the indentation of the folded scalar. Since all other lines are more indented, they start with space characters and thus all line breaks are kept.

The second issue is that you seem to assume that YAML recognizes comments within a folded scalar, which it doesn't. A folded scalar treats all contained characters as content. Since what you intend to be comments are treated as content, so is the whitespace before those comments.

There are only two ways of commenting a folded scalar in YAML:

```yaml
folded: >    # at the header line
  Lorem ipsum
  Dolor sit amet
 # At the end, with the initial `#` being less indented than the first line
```

Everything else will be treated as content. There's not way around it with folded (`>`) or literal (`|`) scalars.

Comment: Ah! This explanation is perfect. I hadn't realized the `(?x)` was critical. Also, I ended up using `|+` to capture the newlines exactly as is, otherwise the comments were screwing up the regex. Thanks for the explanation!